# synchronize the states between multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a table and several bots (for now 2 only) that are trying to find the shortest path in the table from the starting point to the goal.

Each bot is a thread that keeps the state of blocked and not-blocked cells in the table.

Each thread is subscribed to other threads. When some thread performs and move, it sends notification to other threads that it has released the previously occupied cell and blocked another.

It looks like this

[image]

The main loop of each thread looks like this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // render original position
    notifyObserver(ChangeStateEvent
        .builder()
        .identifier(npc.getIdentifier())
        .newState(
            NPCWalkState.builder()
                .row(startVertex.getRow())
                .column(startVertex.getColumn())
                .build())
        .build());
    while (!startVertex.equals(goalVertex)) {
        ThreadUtils.delaySeconds(speed);

        Vertex nextStep = pathSearch.find(startVertex, goalVertex, cellStates).get(1);

        ChangeStateEvent event = ChangeStateEvent.builder()
            .identifier(npc.getIdentifier())
            .newState(
                NPCWalkState.builder()
                    .row(nextStep.getRow())
                    .column(nextStep.getColumn())
                    .build())
            .previousState(
                NPCWalkState.builder()
                    .row(startVertex.getRow())
                    .column(startVertex.getColumn())
                    .build())
            .build();
        notifyObserver(event);
        startVertex = new Vertex(nextStep);
    }
}
```

And listener method looks like this

```
@Override
public void receiveNotification(ChangeStateEvent data) {
    if (null != data.getPreviousState()) {
        // freed cells
        int free_row = data.getPreviousState().getRow();
        int free_column = data.getPreviousState().getColumn();
        // blocked cells
        int blocked_row = data.getNewState().getRow();
        int blocked_column = data.getNewState().getColumn();

        cellStates[free_row][free_column] = false;
        cellStates[blocked_row][blocked_column] = true;
    } else {
        // blocked cells
        int blocked_row = data.getNewState().getRow();
        int blocked_column = data.getNewState().getColumn();

        cellStates[blocked_row][blocked_column] = true;
    }
}
```

`cellStates` is a basic boolean matrix

```
private boolean[][] cellStates;
```

But sometimes those moving bots are overlap each other - so they enter the same cells at the same time. In the end they achieve the desired destination.

**However I'd like to get rid of this behaviour. How to achieve that?**

As far as I understand I should prevent search until the state of `cellState` is updated in `receiveNotification` message or prevent updating `cellState` if search started.

I also don't exclude that the table itself is responsible for that overlapping - as it is subscribed to thread events too

```
@Override
public void receiveNotification(ChangeStateEvent data) {
    if (null != data.getPreviousState()) {
        int previousRow = data.getPreviousState().getRow();
        int previousColumn = data.getPreviousState().getColumn();
        int currentRow = data.getNewState().getRow();
        int currentColumn = data.getNewState().getColumn();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            List<T> oldCellContent = (List<T>) table.getValueAt(previousRow, previousColumn);
            oldCellContent.remove(data.getIdentifier());
            table.setValueAt(oldCellContent, previousRow, previousColumn);

            List<T> newCellContent = (List<T>) table.getValueAt(currentRow, currentColumn);
            newCellContent.add(0, (T) data.getIdentifier()); // on top TODO: player should be prioritized
            table.setValueAt(newCellContent, currentRow, currentColumn);
        });
    } else {
        int currentRow = data.getNewState().getRow();
        int currentColumn = data.getNewState().getColumn();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            List<T> newCellContent = (List<T>) table.getValueAt(currentRow, currentColumn);
            newCellContent.add(0, (T) data.getIdentifier());
            table.setValueAt(newCellContent, currentRow, currentColumn);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The image you've posted indicates this is some sort of game. If so, wouldn't allowing arbitrary move orders be counter productive? Let's say the npc chase the player, shouldn't the player be allowed to always move first? That being said one solution might be to have the bots just calculate the next move and submit that to some single thread that sequentially tries to execute the moves and handles any arising conflicts (such as the player and an npc trying to occupy the same cell).

Comment: Events are delayed, you shouldn't use them to synchronize state in different places, that ultimately creates different state in different places. Think about 1 place (=thread) that decides all things and your bots ask that one manager whether they can advance into cell x/y through 2-way notifications. Or get rid of all the threads. They aren't the solution to everything.

Comment: @zapl so you suggest to use single table and provide synchronized access to that? or single event loop for all threads?

Comment: @Thomas player will act separately. they are not chasing - basically walking NPC on some street. I am planning to introduce pattern behaviour (like for example some convoy) but for now I have just A* path finding.

Comment: Either simply synchronized so that there is a single state object and bots need to lock it to change the global state or through notifications: Imagine 2 bots sending message like "advance to 2/2" to some manager thing. Now manager sequentially handles those messages, the first gets response "ok, you're 2/2", the second gets response "no, blocked, stay where you are" and it has to come up with a new plan. The delay between sending and receiving messages now becomes irrelevant because only the manager decides using it's own view of the world.

Comment: @zapl how to achieve that? I mean to notify back that it should recalculate the path? as far as I can see in my implementation this problem also exists.

Comment: @lapots - with a messaging queue shared between the state-management service and any/all participating entities, regardless of their thread status.  rather than all the threads being subscribed to one another, have them all subscribe to the single service to manage system state, resolve resource management conflicts.  one service per managed resource.

Comment: @theRiley but how it resolves the conflict when the thread sends notification to move (calculated it) but some thread was faster and has moved to the cell already?

Comment: @lapots The service queue serializes requests from disparate clients/threads, thus avoiding contention - the service can then make state changes and broadcast them to any/all subscribers notifying as to the state change. pretty much what Thomas & Zap have been saying.  Queues are most likely your ticket to a sane state management architecture for multiple interacting threads contending for shared resources.

Comment: but to calculate the path it should know what cells are available and which cells are not.

Comment: it feels like locking the whole table with states might be the easiest solution - lock table, find path, update table with next locked cell, release lock. or you meant to keep state table for each thread but update it in event loop?

Comment: @lapots Have a service, or services, manage the state of the cell table or other contented for resource, submit move requests to it (enter requests onto the service queue), with listeners for state-change notifications.  the service (or services) maintains state for all participating entities/threads.  If performance is an issue, the service queues can be scaled out.

Comment: @theRiley what I don't particularly understand how to maintain state for all threads with manager approach. For now I came up with synchronized search context only. Where basically I create single search context and pass it to each thread. Context has synchronized search method that performs search, updates state table and notify table to render the next item.

Comment: @lapots - Perhaps I misunderstand you, I'm not sure.  What I am saying is that all threads delegate state management entirely to the service/services.  i.e.: all state is managed via services, which are implemented thru queues which serve to marshall/serialize requests and thus avoid contention.  Any change in state whatsoever is requested via a queue submission.  Service responses may be broadcast to listeners who may update their state status accordingly.  Implicit in this architecture is that entities' notion of their state & its changes must pend upon notification from the service/s.

Comment: @theRiley so in the end each thread has its own state and some central has its own state?

Comment: @lapots - each thread has a state.  all thread states are managed by the service/services, which broadcast thread state-changes back to the threads.  state management or state transitions, to be precise, are delegated by the threads to the services.  that's all I can say on the subject !

Comment: I see. so basically the difference with mine approach is that the threads don't exchange states between each other but instead some additional entity send messages to thread

Comment: Sorry, wasn't available yesterday but better late than never :) - You could also have a look at Redux which is the name of a JS library but actually more of a pattern. Here you have one (read) state that all threads could operate on (e.g. calculate the path based on the current world state). As we've already suggested any changes would be sent to the central store/manager which tries to incorporate them into the central (write) state and if that succeeded updates the read states that the threads are seeing. Any update failures would be sent back to the issuer for a retry.

Comment: We're using Redux in a web ui to handle similar problems (granted ours are about a single UI but yours are about a single world :) ): multiple user actions might trigger AJAX requests and because we don't know when and how they'll be finished so we can't block/synchronize or wait for them to finish in the correct order - much like what your NPC threads would do.